# prove that $n^{13}-n\equiv 0\mod(2730)$ by generalizing Fermat's little theorem.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

When I saw this problem, it came to me that Fermat's little theorem that says:$$a^p\equiv a\mod(p)$$can also been said in general:
$$a^{1+(p-1)k}\equiv a\mod(p)$$
Ad since $13$ can be written as:$$1+(2-1)12=13\\1+(3-1)6=13\\1+(5-1)3=13\\1+(7-1)2=13\\1+(13-1)1=13$$Therefor $$n^{13}\equiv n\mod(2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot13=2730)$$
But I didn't find a way to prove this generalization $a^{1+(p-1)k}\equiv a\mod(p)$. Maybe someone can help me prove it?

Thanks.

Comment: On the other side the generalization follows immediately from the Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: I didn't see there a proof of this general theorem.

Comment: How is that immediately?

Comment: $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ by Fermat's Little Theorem. This means that: $a^{1 + (p-1)k} \equiv a \cdot (a^{p-1})^k \equiv a \cdot 1^k \equiv a \pmod p$

Comment: So it's like multiplying by $1^k$, right.

Comment: Not exactly. You just substitute $a^{p-1}$ with $1$, as $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a \equiv 0\mod p$: Done.

If $a$ is not divisible by $p$, Fermat's Little Theorem can be written as:
$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$.
And so:

$$a^{1+(p-1)k} = a.(a^{p-1})^k \equiv a(1)^k \equiv a\mod p. $$